# How to create a simple question source placeholder in exam class?

Tags: exam, questionnaire

The following the output i get from my MWE given below:

[image]

Note that, I have defined a command `\qfrom` to add the source of the question in each case. It will be empty when the source of the question is unknown.

## How to make this work like the following output?

[image]

or the `qfrom` can be in the left margin.
[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{exam}
\pointname{}
\pointsinrightmargin

\newcommand{\qfrom}[1]{\hfill{[#1]}}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paper = a4paper,
outer = 3in
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question[10]
    Why is there air?

    \question[15] \qfrom{JAM2018}
    How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck
    wood?

\qformat{\thequestion. \textbf{[\thequestiontitle]}\hfill}

    \titledquestion{Title of the Quesiton}[10] \qfrom{NEST2015}
    Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$. 

  \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

PS: I need titled question also for some reason, so i didnt want to format that.

Comment: Hi @David, it looks like the MWE is missing from your code. Can you add it please?

Comment: @Tom Sorry...Added the mwe now...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that tries to solve your question. First of all is that `\qform` must be called before the actual question. It saves its parameter to a macro called `\qfromsource`. The macro is used later on.

Next, we redefine the `\droppoints` macro from the `exam` class to prints the macro `\qfromsource` together with the points assigned to the question.

Before starting the questions, `\qfromat` has to be called with `\droppoints` in it. See code.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\pointname{}
\pointsinrightmargin

\newcommand{\qfrom}[1]{\global\def\qfromsource{#1}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paper = a4paper,
outer = 3in,
}

\makeatletter
\def\droppoints{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill
  \rlap{\hskip\rightmargin  % Defined by the list environment
        \hskip\@rightmargin % Defined by exam.cls
        \hskip-\rightpointsmargin
        \llap{[\qfromsource] (\thepoints)}%
  }% rlap
  \par
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \qformat{\thequestion. \textbf{[\thequestiontitle]}\droppoints}

    \qfrom{JAM2018}
    \titledquestion{Some physics}[5]
    Why is there air?


    \qfrom{JAM2018}
    \titledquestion{Question for dyslectics}[15]
    How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck
    wood?


    \qfrom{NEST2015}
    \titledquestion{Simple integration}[10]
    Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$. 

  \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]